# “Reasonably good” vs “Unusually good”

Tags: vocabulary

I asked this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280480/reasonably-good-or-unusually-good) as a guest and now I have another question as a registered user because I can not comment there!

What is the difference between these two sentences' meaning?

1.She writes reasonably good children's ​books.

2.She writes unusually good children's ​books.

**Edit:**

Hans Christian Andersen writes ......... good children's ​books.

a) unusually
b) Reasonably

Comment: What does the dictionary tell you about *reasonably* and *unusually*?

Answer (score 1):

> 1.She writes reasonably good children's ​books.

This means exactly what is implied; the books she writes are reasonably good.

> 2.She writes unusually good children's ​books.

This means something different; this means that it is not expected that she writes good children's books or that the level of quality is unexpectedly high.

Comment: Do you mean that if she is a famous person we use the first sentence not the second one?

Comment: The latter part of this answer is not correct. _Unusually_ does not mean _surprisingly_ or _unexpectedly_. If you say that Hans Christian Andersen writes unusually good children's tales, you're not expressing any surprise at this fact (which would be an odd thing to do anyway, since he is one of the most widely acclaimed writer of children's tales in the world). You're simply saying that his children's books are good to a degree that is not common or usual.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence suggests that her books are decent.  Not bad, but not outstanding.  The second sentence indicates that her books are really excellent.